# MySQL, how to sort according to categories?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I know how to `select` and sort one category separately and how to `select` and sort all categories according to `ASC` or `DESC`. My question is how to `select` all categories and sort them in the way that for instance fifth category will be on first place and others behind it?

Comment: use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: What means "fifth category"? Do you have it's name or just the 5th place?

Comment: You're going to have to provide some sample data.

Comment: Yes, could give me some code example?

Comment: category has id, name and so on... the fifth place is the example, simply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that *fifth category* just means that you want to prefer a specific category like `Category-Name`, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.Tablename t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.Category = 'Category-Name' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC,
         Category ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `field()` function

```
select *
from categories
order by field(id,5) desc,id
```

or

```
select *
from categories
order by id= 5 desc,id
```